# How do I convert timestamp string to local time string?

Tags: java, android, date, format

I have timestamp string: `"1989-01-01 00:00:00"` and i need convert it to local date format.

I execute:

```
SimpleDateFormat TIMESTAMPFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
DateFormat.getDateFormat(getContext()).format(TIMESTAMPFORMAT.parse("1989-01-01 00:00:00"));
```

And getDateFormat returns `31.12.1988`

Why?

How can I receive `01.01.1989`???

Comment: dd.mm.yyyy - is correct date format only for my locale! I need show date to user in correct for him format

Comment: that's not a timestamp, that's a string.

Comment: timestamp is a notion, string is a visible representation

Comment: why do you need to parse it ? can't you receive it as a long ?

Comment: still. it indicates a time without a timezone. it could be the day before in the right timezone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to skip time-zone when formatting, I would suggest you to set it to default as below:

```
SimpleDateFormat TIMESTAMPFORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
TIMESTAMPFORMAT.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably to do with the time zones involved. I strongly suspect that you're *formatting* in a different time zone to the one you're using for *parsing*, and the value goes to before midnight, basically. If you can use the same time zone on both, it's likely to work.

If you possibly can, I'd encourage you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead though - you really want a `LocalDate`.